# Unable to get min value of DataFrame column with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to get the min value of values in a column of times. If I take a subset of the data I'm able to do it:

```
print(df7.ix[3,'START_TIME'].min())
type(df7.ix[3,'START_TIME'].min())
```

output is returned correctly:

```
09:17:09
str
```

But if I try on the entire column this error is returned:

```
print(df7['START_TIME'].min())
```

output:

```
TypeError: unorderable types: str() <= float()
```

So there is some bad data that is tripping up the min method. Is there any way to call the method and skip the bad data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you have both floats and strings in that one column.

See if this works:

```
print(df7['START_TIME'].astype(str).min())
```

If it does, then you also have floats in that column.  You want to find them and deal with them.

```
my_floats_indices = [i for i, v in df7['START_TIME'].iteritems() if isinstance(v, float)]
```

Then look at them with

```
df7.loc[my_floats_indices, 'START_TIME']
```

See if you can fix your problem.  Hope that helps.